# Cytoscape AnatApp plugin: Error when loading a new subnetwork

Tags: cytoscape

I have been trying to get AnatApp (https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/anatapp) to work in Cytoscape. I can install it either through the AnatApp weblink or through cytoscape user interface (the App manager). Either installs AnatApp but when I open ANAT and click "new subnetwork" or "new background network" I get an error message saying "Retrieving available networks... Network problem". It says "caught exception executing task" in the error log.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa), java version 11.0.17, and I have tried to get AnatApp to work using versions of Cytoscape 3.9.1, 3.8.2, and 3.8.0. I get exactly the same error message for all the versions.

Does anyone know whether this is maybe a firewall issue or an incompatibility issue (e.g. the plugin is not compatible with my version of java?).

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to the app authors, which you can reach by looking them up on the Cytoscape app store.